# Optimal way of populating a check field or adding it to a document via SignNow?

Tags: python, signnow

I am using SignNow to create and pre-fill documents. I am facing issues while working with checkboxes. In their API documentation, I couldn't find any way of checking/unchecking a checkbox but there is a way of adding checkboxes to the document with predefined values. Problem in the later one is that it takes coordinates as parameters and that too in absolute values so responsiveness is compromised. Can someone guide me with a better approach or alternative to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem by working with second approach of sending checkbox fields with coordinates. Problem which I was facing earlier was due to coordinates which I was taking from SignNow web portal which was quite different than from PDF layout. I added couple of check boxes from web portal, downloaded that document as PDF and used it to find actual coordinates and then consumed them in respective APIs.